# Unable to identify .class files which are added as a external customized jar to the application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I created a external customized jar file for a dao and model package using maven and i am importing that jar file in client application where i want to access the dao methods,but it's giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/test/users/dao/UserDao but the .class files are existing in the jar file. I am able to see the package and methods of that particular customized jar file inside the client web application.
In Service side project,which we are going to make it as a jar for the client application, the maven pom file is having following dependence

groupId-- com.test

artifactId--service

name--testServiceGjcp

packaging--jar

version--1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT

from the above dependence properties groupid,aritfact id and version,we made it available in the client application maven pom.xml file as a dependence then we added the generated service jar file inside the client maven dependence and build the client application,jar has been created and able to see the .class files inside the generated jar file.

In Service Project Structure is as below
[image]

But still we are getting the  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError even though .class files and its corresponding package as well as method of that particular .class file are existing.

Here i am pasting the complete stack trace of the actual error.

```
11:39:34.466 [http-bio-8080-exec-18] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/SpringSecurity/login]
```

11:39:34.479 [http-bio-8080-exec-18] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /login
11:39:34.481 [http-bio-8080-exec-18] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.test.controller.MainController.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
11:39:34.481 [http-bio-8080-exec-18] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mainController'
11:39:34.481 [http-bio-8080-exec-18] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/SpringSecurity/login] is: -1
11:39:34.543 [http-bio-8080-exec-18] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/users/dao/UserDao
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/users/dao/UserDao
    at com.test.users.service.MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(MyUserDetailsService.java:31) ~[MyUserDetailsService.class:na]
    at com.test.controller.MainController.login(MainController.java:53) ~[MainController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.users.dao.UserDao
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Apr 06, 2016 11:39:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/SpringSecurity] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/users/dao/UserDao] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.users.dao.UserDao
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at com.test.users.service.MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(MyUserDetailsService.java:31)
    at com.test.controller.MainController.login(MainController.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your real issue is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/users/dao/UserDao at com.test.users.service.MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(MyUserDetailsService.java:31)`.

I suspect a ClassLoader issue, for example if `MyUserDetailsService` and `UserDao` are located in two different web apps, they will be in two different (isolated) ClassLoaders such that they won't be able to see each other. They need to be located in the same Classloader (root classloader or web app classloader) or UserDao could be located in the root classloader (the parent calssloader of the webapp classloader) while MyUserDetailsService is located in a web app classloader

Comment: Yes MyUserDetailService.java is from one web application and the UserDao is from other application.I am making the UserDao as jar and making it available to MyUserDetailsService which is a client web application.Can you please elaborate more about the Class loader ,how to make it as root class loader and web app class loader.

Comment: It depends on the Application Server/Servlet Engine that you use, but assuming that you use Tomcat for example, you will have the Bootstrap  that contains the basic runtime classes provided by the JVM + what you have in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext, the System class loader basically what you have in the CLASSPATH, the Common classloader that is globally what you have in tomcat/lib and finally Webapp Classloader that is what you have in WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib. In this case what I call root class loader is the common classloader, so you would need to put the jar of UserDao in tomcat/lib.